# Xamarin validation

Tags: c#, validation, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

Before I have already done an update to the nuget package Xamarin.Forms, my application worked correctly, when I clicked on the button "Sacuvaj", if I had errors, it would print a certain message. After the update package, when I click on the button "Sacuvaj", the message is not printed and the background becomes light blue. Also the redirect doesn't work, while in the previous version everything worked properly. Where is the problem?

Comment: Which nuget package did you update?  You also haven't shown any code so it's impossible to suggest what the problem might be.

Comment: Nuget package - Xamarin.Forms . There are pictures : 
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHFvz.png

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTbpg.png

Comment: Did you get any exception? Try to re-install Xamarin.forms nuget package and clean/rebuild your project, then try again.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT No, I didn't with last version Xamarin.Forms. For those who has this problem, update nuget package Xamarin.Forms to version 4.4.0.991265 and it will work fine :)

Comment: You can write the solution in the answer, then accept it which will help more people with same problem:).